# XORing two strings outputs blank string

Tags: c++, string, char

The offending code

```
string foo(string a, string k) {
   string output;

   for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
      output[i] = a[i] ^ k[i]; 
   }

   return output;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps they start with the same character. Or perhaps the XOR produces non-printable characters until two match, or maybe the XOR for all of the characters produces non-printable characters, or maybe the two strings are of different lengths and nothing is printed because undefined behaviour. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help.

Comment: How are you verifying that it is an "empty string" there is a high likelyhood that the characters created are not printable...

Comment: I just cout'ed it, and nothing came out with test inputs "test", "whyy".

Comment: @user3880774, In this case it's clear. I missed it, but there's undefined behaviour if `a.size()` is not 0, as stated in the answer. Judging from your expectations, it is not 0. Anyway, if you want to determine the contents of a string, printing it won't always work. There could be whitespace or non-printable characters. A simple modification is to put quotation marks or something around the output and print the length alongside it. It won't show you non-printable characters, but you'll know they're there.

Comment: no, it returns a string of 0 chars

Comment: @user3880774, Which part are you denying? If it's "it is not 0", that's in reference to `a.size()`.

Answer (score 6):

`string output;` creates an empty string. Going `output[i]` causes undefined behaviour for accessing beyond the bounds of the string.

Add in first:

```
output.resize( a.size() );
```

Also consider checking `if ( k.size() < a.size() ) throw .....`

Comment: string output(a.size()); throws an error, but I resolved that by instead using string output; output = a;

Comment: the two strings are equivalent in length

Comment: You're right, there is no constructor `std::string` with one length argument.  Your option is good although you could do it in one line with `string output = a;`

Comment: I've got a new error now, it says "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions"; indicating the "<" in i < a.size()

Comment: @user3880774, That's a warning and it means you should be using the same type `size()` returns, which is `std::string::size_type`. Specifically, comparing signed and unsigned integers can lead to unexpected results. What would be better when you learn about algorithms is a call to `std::transform`.

Comment: The warning would be indicating a problem if your string were longer than `INT_MAX` ; at this stage the compiler hasn't figured out that you never call it with a string that long